# Get type of interface for scala from java

Tags: java, scala, types

I am generating some scala source code from java. The result is like this:

```
def monitor(value: => Builder[com.test.Monitor]): this.type = inject("monitor", value)
```

The type in the Builder is generated. I have done it like this:

```
private static String constructGenericScalaTypeName(Class type) {
    String name = type.getName();
    if (name == null || name.isEmpty()) {
        name = "_";
    }
    return name;
}
```

But this is not working all the time. For example if I have something like this:

```
public interface ExceptionCatcher<T>
```

The result I believe would have to be:

```
def monitor(value: => Builder[com.test.ExceptionCatcher[_]]): this.type = inject("catcher", value)
```

Is there some way how this can be done properly?

Answer (score 0):

I have one not very nice sollution:

```
private static String constructGenericScalaTypeName(Class type) {
    String name = type.getName();
    if (name == null || name.isEmpty()) {
        name = "_";
    } else {
        TypeVariable<Class>[] types = type.getTypeParameters();
        if (types.length != 0) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(name);
            builder.append("[");
            for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
                builder.append("_,");
            }
            builder.delete(builder.length() -1, builder.length());
            builder.append("]");
            name = builder.toString();
        }
    }
    return name;
}
```